# How to set project file name in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am writing an Android app using IntelliJ IDEA.

My project file is generated as android.iml because my project folder is named android.

The project folder of my partner is named cleverlotto (app name). Because of this IntelliJ generates a second project file named cleverlotto.iml.

[image: Project Structure]

Now we are working with different project settings.

So how can we use the same project file without using the same project folder name?

Comment: do you share the iml files via a version control system with your partner?

Comment: yes, we are using git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question to Jetbrains Support.

Answer:

> It is not possible to rename root module without also renaming root
>   directory of the project.